# How to publish electron app to GitHub releases using electron builder?

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I am trying to publish my electron app to GitHub releases but I cannot get it to work.

This is what I have:

`package.json`

```json
....
"scripts": {
    "start": "electron . --disable-gpu",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "win": "electron-builder --windows nsis:ia32",
    "linux": "electron-builder --linux",
    "publish":"electron-builder -p onTag"
  }, 
 ....
"build": {
    "publish": [
      "github"
    ],
....
}
```

when I run `npm run publish` it creates the executable but it does not publish on my GitHub releases repository:

```
$ npm run publish                                                                            

> Inventory-pro@1.0.1 publish /home/xander/Develop/Electron/InventoryV2
> electron-builder -p onTag

  • electron-builder  version=21.2.0 os=5.3.0-26-generic
  • loaded configuration  file=package.json ("build" field)
  • writing effective config  file=dist/builder-effective-config.yaml
  • packaging       platform=linux arch=x64 electron=7.1.3 appOutDir=dist/linux-unpacked
  • building        target=deb arch=x64 file=dist/Inventory-pro_1.0.1_amd64.deb
```

I want to publish it so that I can include auto-update on my app on every release.

Comment: Did you set GH_TOKEN as an environment variable?

Answer (score 0):

Don't specify the `-p` option and it will always publish a release because your script in the `package.json` is named `release`.

> But please consider using automatic rules instead of explicitly specifying `publish`:
>
> - If npm script named `release`, — `always`.

Source: https://www.electron.build/configuration/publish#how-to-publish

```json
...
"scripts": {
...
    "publish":"electron-builder"
  }, 
...
```